# how does a class as a data type or return type works. Can some one please tell,

Tags: java, c#, complex-data-types

```
public class className{  
int number;  
string name;  
public ClassName(int d) {  //What will return from this method??
    d = 10 ;  
    name = "ABC";  
}
```

}

I cant figure out how does a class as a data type or return type works. Can some one please tell, show or teach me how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of a class as a custom datatype.
We have strings, which represent words.
We have ints, which represent whole numbers.
There is no native datatype for Node, which you want to have a data and next property.
As you pass the Node class like you would any other datatype, but will have information on the Node data and Node next, not just a string or int.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to read about [The C# and .NET type system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/), the docs is a good place to start.